# Negative Lookahead & Lookbehind with Capture Groups and Word Boundaries

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind, word-boundary

We are auto-formatting hyperlinks in a message composer but would like to avoid matching links that are already formatted.

Attempt: Build a regex that uses a negative lookbehind and negative lookahead to exclude matches where the link is surrounded by `href="` and `"`.

Problem: Negative lookbehind/lookahead are not working with our regex:

Regex:

```
/(?<!href=")(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_+.~#?&\/\/=;]*)(?!")/g
```

Usage:

```
html.match(/(?<!")(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=;]*)(?!")/g);
```

When testing, we notice that exchanging the *negative* lookahead/lookbehind with a *positive* version causes it to work. Thus, only *negative* lookbehind/lookaheads are not working.

Does anyone know why these *negative* lookbehind/lookaheads are not functioning with this regex?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide some sample text that cause incorrect matches?

Comment: FYI you don't need to escape `+` inside `[]`

Comment: This is the string I tried it on (in the browser console) where I noticed that the positive lookbehind/ahead works, but the negative lookbehind/ahead doesnt:

`<div>Hey everyone - <a href="https://example.com/annotated-charts/" target="_blank">Annotated Charts</a> are now up-to-date and <a href="https://example.com/daily-market-analysis/" target="_blank">January 2023 Daily Market Comments</a> https://example.com/annotated-charts/</div>`

The final link should be matched. The first two links (that are formatted with <a> tags) should not be matched.

Comment: Is `//=;` a copying error? You need to escape `/` in the regexp. I had to change that to `\/=;` to make the regexp valid.

Comment: The problem is that `https://` is optional. So it matches the part of the URL after that, since it's not preceded by `href="`

Comment: Shouldn't the negative lookahead still work with the optional `https://` ?

Comment: No, because the part before that is quantified with `*`. So it can just match a shorter part of the URL so it stops before the `"`. See https://regex101.com/r/nFKznG/1 -- it's not including the last `/` in the match.

Comment: Basically, anything that allows  something to be optional next to a negative lookaround may negate the effect of the lookaround, if it can find a shorter match that isn't next to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @Barmar's help in the question comments, it is clear that the problem lies in the optional beginning and end of the regex.

"Basically, anything that allows something to be optional next to a negative lookaround may negate the effect of the lookaround, if it can find a shorter match that isn't next to it. "

Answer (score 1):

If using modern JS that supports variable length lookbehind assertions, you can
utilize non-greedy variability into the lookbehind.

This allows the regex to now introduce optional beginnings like what you have.

```
/(?<!href="[^"]*?)(?:https?:\/\/.)?(?:www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9#%+\-.:=@_~]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b[a-zA-Z0-9#%&+\--\/:;=?@_~]*(?!")/
```

https://regex101.com/r/OdJyZf/1

```
 (?<! href=" [^"]*? )
 (?: https?:// . )?
 (?: www \. )?
 [a-zA-Z0-9#%+\-.:=@_~]{2,256} \. [a-z]{2,6} \b [a-zA-Z0-9#%&+\--/:;=?@_~]* 
 (?! " )
```

I must make a correction. In my comments I said that
the word boundary `\b` here `[a-z]{2,6}\b[a-zA-Z0-9#%&+\--/:;=?@_~]` effectively removes the word class `\w` in the following class.

This is true but only for the first following letter. All the following chars seem to include word chars so it's needed.
It's a clear example of overthinking something that does not need to be.

The whole regex should be able to be rewritten using `\w` in the classes unless ASCII is required.

Note that this will only work for the new JS engine and C# (of course).